# How to add a vertical Scroll in this HTML/JQUERY code?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I'm getting a struggle here to get a vertical scroll working. Here is the HTML/JQUERY code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>teste1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
html {
font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}
#conteudo, #oculto {
background: #e5e5e5;
width: 480px;
margin: auto;
padding: 10px;
border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
#conteudo h1 {
font-size: 15px;
}
#oculto {
display: none;
margin-top: 30px;
overflow: scroll; 
width: 200px; 
height: 100px;
}
</style>    

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("h1#mostra").click(function() {
                $("div#oculto").toggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="conteudo">
    // Aqui o elemento que exibe o elemento oculto
    <h1 id="mostra">Clique aqui para exibir/ocultar um elemento</h1>
    </div>

    // aqui o elemento oculto
    <div id="oculto">
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
        dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to add a scroll to the "#oculto". I have added this code but it is not working:

```
#oculto {
display: none;
margin-top: 30px;
overflow: scroll; 
width: 200px; 
height: 100px;
}
```

My question. It is possible to add a scroll in this situation?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this -> http://jsfiddle.net/Husar/yYcsU/92/  possibly what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove the "display: none;" entry.

UPDATE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>teste1</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>


        <style type="text/css">
            html {
            font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            }
            #conteudo, #oculto {
            background: #e5e5e5;
            width: 480px;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 10px;
            border: solid 1px #ccc;
            }
            #conteudo h1 {
            font-size: 15px;
            }

        </style>    



    </head>

    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#mostra").click(function() {          
            $(".oculto").toggle("slow");
            });
            });
        </script>

        <div id="conteudo">
            // Aqui o elemento que exibe o elemento oculto
            <h1 id="mostra">Clique aqui para exibir/ocultar um elemento</h1>
        </div>

        // aqui o elemento oculto
        <div id="oculto" class="oculto">
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />
            dddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd<br />

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it is not working. After I do a toggle does not work any more. Some clues?

Comment: #oculto style is defined twice. Perhaps they are conflicting?

Comment: With the UPDATEed code above... this seems to work... Be careful specifying ID or CLASS in jquery.  ID is ".xxx" and CLASS is "#xxx".